# MQTT mosquitto - set up client for intermediate CA

Tags: ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto, ca

I have created CA, intermediate CA and certificates signed by intermediate CA by these commands:

```
CA:
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -extensions v3_ca -subj "/C=CZ/ST=aa/L=bb/O=company/OU=development/CN=ca/" -nodes -x509 -sha256 -set_serial 0 -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt

Intermediate CA:
openssl genrsa -out subca.key 4096
openssl req -new -key subca.key -out subca.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in subca.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out subca.crt -extfile openssl.cfg -extensions v3_ca

Server:
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout server.key -subj "/C=CZ/ST=aa/L=bb/O=company/OU=development/CN=server/" -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=IP:177.18.0.1") -days 365 -in server.csr -CA subca.crt -CAkey subca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt

Client:
openssl genrsa -des3 -out client.key 4096
openssl req -new -key client.key -subj "/C=CZ/ST=aa/L=bb/O=company/OU=development/CN=client/" -out client.csr
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA subca.crt -CAkey subca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 365
```

When I verify server or client certificate, everything seems good.
Verify command I use:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile <(cat subca.crt ca.crt) server.crt
```

I want to connect to the mosquitto with TLS/SSl support with these certificates.

Mosquitto configuration:

```
listener 1883
require_certificate false
allow_anonymous true

listener 8883

capath /mosquitto/config/certs/ca/
certfile /mosquitto/config/certs/server.crt
keyfile /mosquitto/config/certs/server.key

require_certificate true
allow_anonymous true
use_identity_as_username true
```

But when I want to connect with my client, I do not know how to set function tls_set() for intermediate CA. Can you help me to setup this function ? When I look to the official documentation https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#option-functions
for function tls_set(), there is sentence that says:

"ca_certs = a string path to the Certificate Authority certificate files that are to be treated as trusted by this client."

But I don't know how to put more certificates there and I cannot use directory as argument.

Client code:

```
client = mqtt.Client(client_id='Monitoring Test',
                     clean_session=None,
                     userdata=None,
                     protocol=mqtt.MQTTv5,
                     transport='tcp')

client.on_message = on_message
client.tls_set(ca_certs="ca-chain.pem",
               certfile="client.pem",
               keyfile="client.key",
               tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

client.connect("177.18.0.1", port=8883, keepalive=60)
client.subscribe("topic", qos=2)
client.loop_forever(timeout=60)
```

I know how to do it for root CA and signed certificate by this CA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hardillb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504554/hardillb) suggested me to use for client:

```
cat subca.crt ca.crt > ca-chain.crt (order is important)
```

When I used it only for client it still did not work, but as soon as I also used file `ca-chain.crt` for server, it works.

So change line `capath /mosquitto/config/certs/ca/` in mosquitto configuration and use `cafile /mosquitto/config/test/ca-chain.pem` instead.

Comment: Ahh, that's because you have now hit a different problem (the broker verifying the client cert not the client verifying the broker cert) to what was asked in the question. Still you have a working solution

Comment: I also suspect you may have forgotten to run `openssl rehash <path to capath>` to index the CA files (this is mentioned in the mosquitto.conf man [page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html))

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a single file that contains all the CA certificates, much in the same way you used `cat subca.crt ca.crt` to pass in a "single" file to the `openssl verify` command.

So `cat subca.crt ca.crt > ca-chain.crt` (order is important)

And then pass the path to that file in the client.

p.s. You probably want `per_listener_settings true` if you are going to require different authentication options per listener and `require_certificate false` on the first listener is not doing anything in much the same way that `allow_anonymous true` for the second listener doesn't do anything useful if you are requiring a client certificate.

Comment: I have got same error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: Edit the question to show your code and the full error including stack trace